# Decode JSON into Symfony entity

Tags: php, serialization, symfony, decode

Does anyone know if there is an easy way, aside from writing a custom script to decode a JSON object into a PHP entity?

I'm using the script below to encode to JSON, but when I decode it's an array and not an entity.

```
$serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new 
            JsonEncoder()));
            $json = $serializer->serialize($coupon, 'json');
            $session->set('json', $json);
```

Then I'm decoding in this manner

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $json = $session->get('json');
    $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
    $coupon = $serializer->decode($json, 'json');
```

But like I said... it's no longer a Coupon entity, it's just an array.

Comment: decode will always return an array, you need to denormalize the data then which will turn it into a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the following works:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$json = $session->get('json');
$serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
$coupon = $serializer->decode($json, 'json');
```

`$coupon` is a normalized array of the serialized data. Then assuming the class you want this data to be instantiated of is called `Coupon`, you need to denormalize it:

```
$coupon = $serializer->denormalize($coupon, 'Coupon');
```

Mind the namespaces, the classname `Coupon` might not be correct.

Comment: hmm.. thats close, but there are entities within the Coupon class.  These are set using setCity($city City) for example, and instead of passing in the object it trys to pass in the Array with all of cities attributes (id, cityname, state etc).  I'm thinking I'll have to parse the entire thing by hand ;/

Comment: Well I won't go that far, but just denormalize the sub-values before you denomarlize the main array. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle).

Its serializer is way more advanced than the serializer that the one from the Serializer Component.

Comment: Could you please list the differences and or pros/cons between the components in your answer ? It's difficult to appreciate its quality with only **way more advanced**.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting option with [JSON class hinting](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/01/the-symfony2-serializer-component-create-a-normalizer-for-json-class-hinting/).